# How do I generate "credentials" issued by "composer identity issue" required to access Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have generated Composer identity via.

```
$ composer identity issue -p hlfv1 -n parcel-network -i admin -s adminpw -u administrator -a '<namespace>#administrator'
An identity was issued to the participant '<namespace>#administrator'
 The participant can now connect to the business network with the following details:
  userID = administrator
  userSecret = kwrDcuzuGvre

Command succeeded
```

Now, how do I create "credentials" to connect to business network ?
The possible work around is to download the wallet, and then create credentials via "composer identity import". But I think this is not correct way.

Thanks !

Comment: Are you running `./createComposerProfile.sh` after starting the network with `startFabric.sh` but before issuing any identity?

Comment: ./createComposerProfile.sh just copies existing credential files under composer/creds. Not issueing new one. My question is related after the composer setup. Suppose new participant (enterprise entity, not person) have joined the network. And this participant requires new identity, and this must be binded. And then new participant require to business network with new identity.

Comment: I know, but when trying to run Composer with authentication/multi-user mode I would run into authentication failures when trying to issue identities or perform actions on the network and the issue ended up being that I had forgotten to run the script, hence why I asked.

Typically I haven't used the command line interface to do identity management. I load up the composer REST server with authentication and multi-user mode enabled, issue identities using the System endpoints, and then bind them to wallets using the Wallet endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I also check wallet apis (looks like experimental). Not sure how this is related to enrollment via BusinessNetworkConnection.connect() .

Comment: The wallet contains identities, and identities are enrolled users in the Fabric network. It's not experimental, this is how Composer does authentication. You can issue a user as you did above, and then enroll it by adding it to a wallet. Adding it to a wallet converts the userID and userSecret into a certificate pair for interacting with the network.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the second command, `adminstrator` (in `composer network ping`) vs the issued identity `administrator`.

Comment: Thanks!  By the way, how about my original question ?  How to generate "credentials" ?

Comment: By the way, I have removed the errors. And put the original question in mind.